# How to deobfuscate Java application protected by Java Antidecompiler

Tags: java, deobfuscation, decompile, jar

Here is some infomation I found from `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: boonb
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_231
Main-Class: JavaLauncher
Modified-By: 9.4 (BIS Guard & Co.)
Protected-By: Java Antidecompiler
```

Does anyone know how to deobfuscate this? I need a keyword, pls.

Answer (score 1):

At first thats not obfuscated but just packed.
BIS Guard is pretty useless at all.

There are two ways to retrieve the encrypted classes:

1. Decompile your jar and reverse the main class of BisGuard (which is deobfuscated)
2. Empty the LDC "-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism" and attach an agent to dump the classes (https://github.com/karim789/class-dumper-agent)